# Unable to import modules from a directory

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, importerror

I have created a file `main.py` which imports `out_handler.py` which imports  `style_generator.py` but every time I try to implement it with import I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mayan\Desktop\food data app with soonacular\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from modules import out_handler
  File "c:\Users\mayan\Desktop\food data app with soonacular\modules\out_handler.py", line 2, in <module>       
    import style_generator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'style_generator'
```

This is the structure of the file system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejMun.png)

This is the code of **main.py**

```py
from modules import out_handler
d = out_handler.out()
d.Print(text='rohan')
```

This is the code of **out_handler.py**

```py
import os
import style_generator
import text_generator

class terminal:
    __data = ''''''
    def get_data() -> str:
        return terminal.__data
    
    def set_data(text: str) -> None:
        terminal.__data = text

    def add_data(text) -> None:
        terminal.__data += text

    def clear() -> None:
        os.system('cls')

class out:
    def Print(self,text,color='',background='',style='',justtify='left',font=''):
        render = ''
        match font:
            case '':
                render = style_generator.Text.out(text,color=color,background=background,style=style)
            case _:
                render = text_generator.styles.style(text,font=font,color=color,background=background,styles=style,justify=justtify)

        terminal.set_data(render)
        print(render)

out().Print(text="Aryan",color='red',style='bright',font='3-d',justtify='right')
```

This is the code of **style_generator.py**

```py
from pyfiglet import Figlet
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
from text_generator import Text

class styles:
    init(autoreset=True)

    def style(text,font,color='',background='',styles = 'normal',justify= 'left'):
        f = Figlet(font,justify=justify)
        result = f.renderText(text)
        return Text.add_style(styles) + Text.add_color(color) + Text.add_background(background) + result
```

i have tried adding __**init__**.py file to the module directory also tried using the syntax `module.file.py`  but could not resolve the issue. I hope you guys have solution

Expecting to find the solution to my imports problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first import worked:

```
from modules import out_handler
```

And since those modules are in the same folder, you can import `style_generator` in the same way:

```
from modules import style_generator
```

Or you can do it this way:

```
from . import style_generator
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for helping me out. Your solution worked. It was bothering me the whole night